# jQuery addClass table issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, whitespace

I have a table that uses the datatables jQuery plugin.

I have the following css to make the last column fit the text:

```
#products tr td:last-child {
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This works perfectly. However, I'm trying to do this on the last two columns and in order to be cross browser, I'm trying to replicate the functionality in jQuery.

I have the following:

```
.fitTableLinks{
  width:1%;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

and the jQuery is:

```
$("#products tr td:last-child").addClass("fitTableLinks");
```

but this doesn't work, yet there aren't any console errors?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: Are you waiting the DOM to be ready?

Comment: Does `#products tr td:nth-last-child(-n + 2)` work?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, Yes, its under a document ready call

Answer (score 0):

I agree that CSS would probably be the best way to handle it as mentioned by Salman A above.  If you want to use jQuery I think you'd have to run your code for each tr.

```
$("#products tr").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.find('td:last-child').addClass("fitTableLinks");
});
```

If you want it for the last two columns, just check the length of the $this.children()

```
$("#products tr").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var secondToLast = $this.children().length - 2;
    $this.find('td:last-child').addClass("fitTableLinks");
    $this.find('td').eq(secondToLast).addClass("fitTableLinks");
});
```